# How to access main Model object on swig?

Tags: javascript, node.js, swig-template

In a swig file I want to see all available properties that it is receiving.

Is there a way to access it? Or can I only access its properties?

.js

```
res.render('list.swig', result);
```

list.swig

```
{{ Model|json }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I think you can do that is to open swig under `node_modules` and go to `/lib/swig.js`. Then find the [code for `renderFile`](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/blob/20b20e72d6a3a0a73f5c322142aff555be5bd707/lib/swig.js#L548).

There are three parameters `pathName`, `locals`, `cb`. You can do a condition check on `pathName` if that is what you are looking for you can log `locals`.